# `KeyError: id` when running a function on OpenERP

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7

I am trying to run a function when page loads on OpenERP7. Function creates a dictionary, which i am trying to return to my many2one control.

Here is my function's code.

```
class deg_form(osv.osv):

    _name = "product.product"
    _inherit = "product.product"  
    _columns = {
         'categ_temps':fields.many2one('product.category','Parent'),       
            }

    def myfunc_name(self,cr,uid,ids,context=None):
        domain=[]
        cr.execute('select id,name from product_category where parent_id is NULL')
        res=cr.fetchall()
        for pid,name in res:
            domain.append((pid))
            print name
            return {'domain':{'categ_temps':[('id','in',domain)]}}         

    _defaults = {'name':'.','categ_temps':myfunc_name}

deg_form()
```

I am trying to run function from `_defaults`. my category has details about field which i want to populate. **When I am trying to load my page, i get this error** :

```
select = map(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict) and x['id'] or x, select)
KeyError: 'id'
```

I tried changing my `return` from `domain` to `value`. I also tried to use function `on_change`. which gave me the result required but after I changed my drop down value.

I am not sure what else I should do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're trying to return something for on_change methods (dict with 'value', 'domain' or 'warning'), but you can't return it like that for field defaults.
as you can see in stacktrace

```
select = map(lambda x: isinstance(x, dict) and x['id'] or x, select)
```

the framework tries to get an int or if it's a dictionary tries to get the value for key 'id'.
you provide neither of them.
as it is a many2one field, your function has to return the id for the table record you want to have as default. so return a simple id or a dictionary like `{'id':<here_your_id>}`

hope that'll help you

Comment: If you may elaborate, with some code. I tried to modify my dictionary to get the `id` but i am still getting same error. Also i dont understand, i have same piece of code for `onchange` but it worked. i changed nothing, so it should return id on first time load of page too.

Comment: ok first off: you won't get ids by using a function in _defaults (as far as i know, please try to debug it; EDIT: to make clear, i mean the parameter ids in your function). and second: you're not using onchange here, so you can't use onchange return behaviour. functions used in _defaults have to return single ids (pure integer nothing more) or a dictionary like {'id':<your_id_here>}.